# list.js - Custom sort function on button click without jQuery

Tags: javascript, sorting, list.js

##### **List.js without jQuery**. It's working as supplied out of the box.

##### Mission:

When a 'List By Price' button is clicked, sold-out items need to display at the bottom of the sorted list - *regardless of ascending or descending*.

I've begun to develop a customer sort().

```
    list.sort('price', {
      order: 'asc',
      sortFunction: function (a, b) {
        console.log('sorting price');
       // sort mechanics here
      }
  });
```

However, **it executes when list.js initialises (not wanted)** and doesn't execute when the button is pressed (wanted).

---

EDIT: Working code...

NOTE ---> **listjs.com**

```js
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'price' ]
};

var userList = new List('for-sale', options);
```

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
}
td {
  padding:10px; 
}
.sold, .red{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}
.intro + .intro{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="intro"><span class="red">Sold out</span> items should ALWAYS appear at the bottom of the list after being sorted - regardless of ascending or descending sort.</p><p class="intro">The button toggles ascending and descending</p>
<div id="for-sale">
  <button class="sort" data-sort="price">
    Sort by price
  </button>
  <table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="price sold">Sold out</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price sold">Sold out</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To handle the `click`, read about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: So @LouysPatriceBessette, I ignore that list.js is already listening?

Comment: I've added the code @ChrisG. Just found on listjs.com though, an `on(event, callback)` that identifies a `startsort` event that's accessible. Am investigating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **list.js** plugin does not support *exceptions* on the sorting. And sadly, re-ingineering it is not an option that I retain.

---

Calling the `.sort()` function on the instance will simply trigger a sort again... Maybe with a custom `sortFunction`... But that is **not** the key of the issue here.

You want to *partially* sort the list and I can't imagine any custom `sortFunction` to do this.

---

**But!** you can *re-position* some elements after the plugin has correctly its job. Fortunately, there is no delay (due to any effect) on the re-ordering made by **list.js**, so you don't need any `setTimeout` that would be noticable.

You simply need to register an additional event listener. Event listeners execute in the order they where registered... So the one below will execute after the **list.js** one.

```js
// Code slightly adapted from the example on the list.js website
var options = {
  valueNames: ["price"]
};
var userList = new List("for-sale", options);


// Suggested solution for your issue

// Get the list element
let list = document.querySelector(".list");

// Add an event listener on the sort button
document.querySelector(".sort").addEventListener("click", () => {

  // Get an array of all the rows, based on the 'sold' class
  let rows = Array.from(list.querySelectorAll("tr"));

  // Get just the sold out ones
  let soldout = rows.filter((r) => r.querySelector(".sold"));

  // Remove all sold out rows, based on the 'sold' class
  list.querySelectorAll("sold").forEach((s) => s.closest("tr").remove());

  // Re-append them at the end of the list
  soldout.forEach((s) => list.append(s));
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
}

.sold,
.red {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.intro+.intro {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="intro"><span class="red">Sold out</span> items should ALWAYS appear at the bottom of the list after being sorted - regardless of ascending or descending sort.</p>
<p class="intro">The button toggles ascending and descending</p>
<div id="for-sale">
  <button class="sort" data-sort="price">
    Sort by price
  </button>
  <table>
    <!-- IMPORTANT, class="list" have to be at tbody -->
    <tbody class="list">
      <tr>
        <td class="price sold">Sold out</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">90</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price sold">Sold out</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">70</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="price">50</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @LouysPatriceBessette, I was beginning to think the same. Allow list.js to do the sort, and then move the sold items afterwards. How to access the sorted list was troubling me though. You've shown me how, and given a clear explanation too, which is really helpful. You've solved my problem so I'll accept it as the answer, thank you.